# where are the files and dirs "recently used" stored?

Tags: files, directory

On my Ubuntu 12.04, all the gnome applications (such as Nautilus, Evince, gedit, firefox) can access "Recently Used" files and directories, when opening files in them.

1. I wonder where the information about "Recently Used" files and
   directories is stored? I would like to access the "Recently Used"
   files and directories from terminal, by reading such information.
2. KDE and wine applications can't access  "Recently Used" files and
   directories. I wonder why?

Thanks!

Comment: To add a file to this on the command-line, see: https://askubuntu.com/q/831786/2355

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. The **Recently Used** information is stored in a file called `recently-used.xbel` located under the `.local/share` directory per user, the full path being:

   ```
    ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
   ```

It contains metadata on the recent files, like what is the application that opened it, or the application that should display it in its history.

For example, my gedit shows 3 files:

[image]

If I search for gedit in the file, I can surely see 3 "stanzas" because there are 3 files, here's one of them as a sample:

```
<bookmark href="file:///path/to/dsasd" added="2014-07-26T19:22:24Z" modified="2014-07-26T21:52:22Z" visited="2014-07-26T19:22:25Z">
  <info>
    <metadata owner="http://freedesktop.org">
      <mime:mime-type type="text/plain"/>
      <bookmark:groups>
        <bookmark:group>gedit</bookmark:group>
      </bookmark:groups>
      <bookmark:applications>
        <bookmark:application name="gedit" exec="&apos;gedit %u&apos;" modified="2014-07-26T21:52:22Z" count="7"/>
      </bookmark:applications>
    </metadata>
  </info>
</bookmark>
```

2. The `recently-used.xbel` file is [part of the GTK+ toolkit](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16230/what-is-.recently-used.xbel-and-how-do-i-delete-it-for-good/). I tried looking for some documentation on it, but this is the closest I can get:

- **[GtkRecentManager - gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-gnome/docs/gtk/html/GtkRecentManager.html)**
- **[GTK+ 3 Reference Manual: GtkRecentManager](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkRecentManager.html)**

GNOME uses the GTK+ library, while KDE uses the QT library, I assume that's why it doesn't work with KDE. As for wine, I don't know, maybe it's just not designed to work with it.