# How to view recent files from the command-line?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, files

Is it possible to view recently accessed files using a single command in the command-line?

Could you please provide an explanation of what exactly the command does?

Comment: What are "recently accessed files"?

Comment: I would assume Nautilus recent files? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/504371/where-are-the-files-and-dirs-recently-used-stored

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My "recently" is 5 minutes **=)**

```
recently=5
find . -type f -amin "$recently"
```

*Breakdown*

- `find`

  search for files in a directory hierarchy
- `.`

  search in the current folder and all subfolders
- `-type f`

  search only fort files
- `-amin 5`

  File was last accessed 5 minutes ago.

---

Or perhaps you mean the *recently used* files in your Desktop Environment, than you need something like

```
awk -F"file://|\" " '/file:\/\// {print $2}' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

*Breakdown*

- `awk`

  pattern scanning and text processing language
- `-F"file://|\" "`

  define two field separators, `file://` and `"`
- `/file:\/\//`

  only lines with `file://` are interesting
- `{print $2}`

  the path is in column 2

Comment: He probably means ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel

Answer (score 9):

The term recently is relative, I am going to assume last 10 minutes as recent in my answer (change that to fit your need).

Using `find`:

```
find . -type f -amin -10
```

Here the `-amin -10` would find all files (`-type f`) in the current directory and all subdirectories accessed within last 10 minutes.

For files accessed less than 30 minutes ago:

```
find . -type f -amin -30
```

---

Using `zsh`:

```
print -l **/*(.am-10)
```

`**/*` looks recursively for files and the glob qualifier `(.am-10)` finds files (`.`) accessed within the last 10 minutes (`am-10`).

Comment: same comment: he probably means ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel