# Is there a way to add to the "Recently Used" list (that appears in file dialogs) from the command-line?

Tags: command-line, files, places

I have certain scripts that create files (often from keyboard shortcuts) and I would like to have the files they create appear in the "Recently Used" section of file open dialogs. Is there a way to add to this list from the command-line?

For example, I have a script that runs `scrot` with certain options to take a screenshot. I would like the resulting screenshot to then appear in the "Recently Used" section of file open dialogs.

Comment: I think you need to specify the programs whose file open dialogs you are interested in. Different programs track different recently used files.

Comment: @edwinksl Are you sure about that? If I download an image in Chrome, the downloaded image appears in the Recently Used list of GIMP. It seems unlikely that Chrome would have hard-coded support for GIMP.

Comment: Might be possible.  I know for a fact there exists amd xml file somewhere in user home folder that contains recently used files, but I don't recall of the top of my head where it is. Look through some of the questions here on AskUbuntu. I know Jacob Vlijm has used it in his scripts. Once i have time, I'll find it and post and answer unless someone does before me

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Take Nautilus as an example. If I merely create a new file somewhere, say, in my home directory, by using `touch`, the Recent tab in Nautilus is not aware of this new file created. If I click on Open File in my Atom editor, this new file also doesn't show up in the Recently Used tab.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves I should rephrase what I said in my first comment. I think what you see in the file open dialogs depends on how the new files are created.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves As a followup to what Serg said, I think the file in question is `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`.

Comment: @edwinksl Yes, I know that not all newly created files are added to this list -- that's why I'm asking how to add certain files to it. `recently-used.xbel` is a good pointer. I searched for that and found that the relevant API is the `GtkRecentManager`. I don't see a command-line wrapper for it, but will see if I can write one in Python. I'll post that here if I am successful (and no one else beats me to it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Python, this can be done with:

```py
from gi.repository import Gio
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Gtk

...

GLib.set_application_name(appname) # optional: appname is recorded
uri = Gio.File.new_for_path(filename).get_uri()
Gtk.RecentManager.get_default().add_item(uri)
```

A more complete script to do this can be found in [the recently_used github repo](https://github.com/xenomachina/recently_used). Usage is pretty straightforward:

```
$ recently_used.py foo.txt bar.png
```

This adds the files `foo.txt` and `bar.png` to the recently used list used by GTK+ apps.

Comment: Good job on solving your own question !  So `Gtk.RecentManager` writes to `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` by default  ?

Comment: @Serg I was less concerned about the intermediate file, and more about the end result (ie: does the file I want end up in the recently used section of Nautilus and file dialogs?), but I just checked, and it does look like `recently-used.xbel` gets updated by `Gtk.RecentManager`. Actually, looking in there was interesting because I discovered that the app name is also recorded, so I added a flag to the script to change the app name.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually quite useful feature. I recently had to help a user who for some reason had a directory added to the file (which what I think isn't supposed to happen), and we figured out the app was geany for whatever reason, which kind of suggests there's a bug in geany.